# use value to search for column in r

Tags: r, assign

How can cause the row_to_keep command to work with the variable b instead of using the real variable name. Thanks for your help

```
    > names(newdata)
    [1] "Jahr"      "Forstzone" "value,,"  
    > variablennameliste<-list("Year","year","Jahr","jahr")
    > b<-toString(intersect(names(newdata),variablennameliste))
    > print(b)
    [1] "Jahr"
    >row_to_keep = which(newdata$b!=2014)
    Warning message:
    Unknown column 'b'
```

I have tried the

```
    assign()
```

command, but it didn't work

Comment: @Henrik I don't this is a dupe of that question bcz of the OP's code have some elements that don't sync well or answered in that dupe

Answer (score 0):

We need to use `[` to extract the value in the object 'b'

```
which(newdata[,b]!=2014)
```

The `toString` wrapper is not needed as it will convert to a single string separated by the delimiter `,` when there are multiple `intersect`ing elements.  In the example, there is only a single element.

```
b <- intersect(names(newdata),variablennameliste)
```

Even when there are multiple `intersect`ing elements, the above should work as we are selecting the 'newdata' columns based on the 'b' vector.  In that case, the comparison `!=2014` depends on what values the columns have and the objective